# Colorbox-rails gem brings up blank lightbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, colorbox

I've installed the Colorbox-rails gem and followed installation instructions. I'm applying it to a ecommerce product page and want to show product images in a lightbox.

However, when I click on the image, the lightbox opens but it's blank.

Here is the gem page:

https://github.com/stevo/colorbox-rails

Here is the example ruby syntax on the gem page:

```
<%= link_to "My superb link", "#", :data => { :colorbox => true } %>
```

I am linking an image so here is my code. This doesnt work - brings up a blank lightbox.

```
<%= image_tag @listing.image.url, :data => { :colorbox => true } %>
```

I also tried the below but this gives me an error.

```
<%= link_to image_tag @listing.image.url, "#", :data => { :colorbox => true } %>
```

The url call works on it's own as below so it's something to do with the rest of the code.

```
<%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
```

I'd like to add multiple images so users can click on one and then click the arrows to view the slideshow.

How would I do that? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your third example looks like it should work. If you're getting an error though, it may be because it's being interpreted incorrectly. Try adding parentheses to the image_tag call, and see if that helps. As a by-product, it'll be rather a lot easier to read!

Comment: Adding () around the image_tag makes the lightbox show a screenshot of the entire page so it's not pulling from the image url. Other ideas? I also want multiple images to show as a gallery with next/prev arrows as the colorbox demos show.